# Pigeonhole principle and finding the total ways for this

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

The question is:

Given any $7$ positive integers whose sum is $100$, show there are $3$ of the numbers whose sum is at least $43$.

So I'm having trouble identifying the pigeonholes. However, I think I know the pigeons: the total number of solutions $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_7\}$ of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_7 = 100$$
where $x_k\geq 1$ for all $k=1,2,\ldots,7$.

This looks like a partitioning problem (since it says "any $7$ positive integers", so $1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 94 = 100$ is the same as
$94 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 100$),
so I'm not sure if I interpreted it correctly.

Comment: Do you have to use pidgeonhole? Because it can be proven by a different type of argument, by contradiction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Reworded to work with pigeons and pigeonholes, this question is asking: "Say you have 100 pigeons and you wished to stuff them in $7$ [pigeon]holes. Show that there must be some set of $3$ holes such that there are at least $43$ pigeons in them."*

We can start by attempting to evenly distribute the pigeons into the holes, with $14$ per hole and $2$ left over. Since all possible sets of $3$ pigeonholes have only $42$ pigeons in them, when we add the $2$ leftover pigeons, there must be at least one set of $3$ pigeonholes that have at least $43$ pigeons (at least one pigeonhole will have $15$, plus $2$ others of $14$).

Comment: Ah I see. I was too keen on strictly defining pigeonholes and pigeons. Also, it doesn't have to be $100$ pigeons right? It could be as low as $99$?

Comment: Yes, it can be as low as 99 (pigeons times pigeonholes plus 1).

Comment: It is not immediately obvious why the arrangement where all are as evenly distributed as possible forcing a set of three to have at least 43 will imply that *all* arrangements will have a set of three that has at least 43.  It is simply not true that all arrangements will have a hole with at least 15 pigeons and two other holes that have at least 14 pigeons in it.  Take for example the arrangement $(99,1,0,0,0,0,0)$.

Comment: It is *not* a correct proof - it is a *particular construction*. It does prove *"exists"*, but no *"for every"*.

Comment: I thought that it would be valid since this is *the worst case* scenario (using as many of the pigeons as we can so that the pigeonholes do not have more than 14)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose otherwise.  Then for all triples $(x_i,x_j,x_k)$ you have $x_i+x_j+x_k\leq 42$.

Let us add all possible triples together: $(x_1+x_2+x_3)+(x_1+x_2+x_4)+\dots+(x_5+x_6+x_7)$

There are $\binom{7}{3}$ triples so as each triple adds to at most $42$ we can bound the overall sum above by $42\binom{7}{3}$.

Each $x_i$ occurs in the overall sum a total of $\binom{6}{2}$ times, so we may simplify the sum as $\binom{6}{2}x_1+\binom{6}{2}x_2+\dots+\binom{6}{2}x_7$ which as $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_7=100$ simplifies further as $100\binom{6}{2}$

So, we would have $1500=100\binom{6}{2}\leq 42\binom{7}{3}=1470$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Divide the given values into 3 sets, two of three elements and one with a single element. Note that at least one of the given elements is less than or equal to 14. Suppose the set with only one member contains this value. Thus, the sum of the two sets of 3 members is greater than or equal to 86. In fact, at least one of the two groups had a sum of their members greater or equal (in the case of both have the same sum) than 43.

Answer (score 2):

Let arrange the addends with the sum `100` into an non-descending order: $x_1\le x_2\le\dots x_7$.
Let there are only 2 pigeonholes:

1. The `1st` one for the `first 4` (the lowest) addends.
2. The `2nd` one for the `last 3` (the highest) addends.

At least in one of them is at least `43` pigeons.

---

If it is the `2nd` pinhole, the proof is finished (`3` addends with the sum at least `43`).

---

If it is *not* the `2nd` pinhole, it must be the `1st` pinhole.
Let use the pigeonhole principle again.
Now we have:

- at least `58` pigeons (because in the `2nd` pinhole is now at most `42`), and
- `4` addends (pinholes).

The last addend of them (the *greatest* one) must have the value at least `15`.
 So the all `3` consequent elements of the original, `7`-element's non-descending sequence must have value at least `15`, too - so their sum is at least `45`, which is in the contradiction with the assumption of this case.

Comment: That is neat! I haven't seen (or wouldn't have thought) of splitting it up into two cases to apply pigeonhole twice. What made you try this?

Comment: @Natash1 - Maybe some previous experience?